# « Année académique »

Tags: usage, france, académique, université

Peut-on employer en France *année académique* ? Jusqu'aujourd'hui je pensais que l'on pouvait le faire, mais je viens de voir cela :

> En Belgique et en Suisse, synonyme d'universitaire : Année
>   académique.

Cependant aucun de mes collègues ne m'a signalé que c'était un emploi fautif. Ngram illustre qu'*année académique* n'est pas aussi courant qu'*année universitaire* depuis les années soixante, mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi. Est-ce que ça a quelque chose à voir avec Mai 68 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***Année académique*** sera compris mais est considéré aujourd'hui comme un anglicisme, bien que l'usage, en particulier en Belgique et en Suisse soit établi depuis longtemps.

On préférera dire ***année scolaire*** (jusqu'au BAC en France) et ***année universitaire*** pour les études supérieures.

Source: [OQLF](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1954)

Tout ça n'a rien à voir avec Mai 68.

Comment: Effectivement en Belgique l'usage n'est absolument pas incongru mais reste plutôt formel. On emploie aussi très largement le terme "année scolaire" dans un registre plus familier. Par contre j'entends assez rarement le terme "année universitaire". Peut-être parce que la différence n'est pas très grande en terme de calendrier entre  les études secondaires et supérieures ?