# «Office hours» en français

Tags: traduction

Dans un contexte académique, les «office hours» sont une période où un professeur est disponible (habituellement dans son bureau) pour répondre aux questions des étudiants.

Quelle est la meilleure traduction de «office hours» en français?

Comment: Attention *académique* est utilisé en Québec, en Suisse et en Belgique mais n'est pas toujours compris avec ce sens en France où on s'attend plutôt à *universitaire* ou *d'études supérieures*.

Comment: @jlliagre académique est plutôt associé à l'académie française, n'est-ce pas ?

Comment: Voir https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34236/ann%c3%a9e-acad%c3%a9mique pour académique.

Comment: @Dimitris Oui, à l'Académie française ou l'une des quatre autres [académies](https://www.institutdefrance.fr/les-cinq-academies/). Il y a aussi le découpage en trente académies de l'Éducation nationale.

Comment: @dimitris *académique* peut aussi décrire un travail qui respecte (un peu trop) les standards, sans originalité et à l'inverse, *peu académique* sera utilisé pour un travail qui s'écarte des sentiers battus.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***Heures de disponibilité*** semble être utilisé au Canada francophone.

Source: [Affaires universitaires](https://www.affairesuniversitaires.ca/conseils-carriere/conseils-carriere-article/tirer-parti-des-heures-de-disponibilite/):

> Tirer parti des heures de disponibilité
> Nous devons mieux expliquer aux étudiants les avantages des heures de disponibilité et faire preuve de souplesse quant aux modalités des rencontres.

En France, je ne suis pas sûr que la pratique soit très répandue, ou si elle l'est, c'est probablement plus récent.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. Je suis au Canada, alors ça marche parfaitement.

Comment: Effectivement, je confirme. Etant français mais ayant enseigné un an au niveau collégial au Québec, la traduction est bonne, mais ce n'est pas une pratique courante du tout dans l'enseignement universitaire français, hélas.

Answer (score 3):

**Heures de bureau**, selon l'OQLF :

> Heures pendant lesquelles la clientèle ou les visiteurs ont accès à un endroit quelconque.
>
> Le terme *heures d'ouverture* s'emploie dans tous les contextes (commerces, bureaux, entreprises, etc.), alors qu'on peut utiliser le terme *heures de bureau* seulement lorsque ce sont des bureaux.

http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870532

Comment: C'est une bonne traduction d'*office hours* en général, mais elle n'est pas du tout adaptée au contexte de la question.

Comment: @jlliagre Je le trouve aussi imparfait mais c'est employé aussi. On peut se questionner sur la valeur du silence du GDT sur la question spécifique dans le contexte de leur article  qu'on lie dans cette réponse. Je dirais la même chose de Termium essentiellement.

Answer (score 3):

Différentes analogies sont possibles. Je ne sais pas ce qui est le plus courant au Canada mais j'ai trouvé assez rapidement dans des plans de cours etc. :

> [Heures/période de disponibilité](https://wiki.umontreal.ca/display/EBSI/Guide+du+personnel?preview=/124098127/162486707/Guide-personnel_2020-2021_20200817.pdf).
>  [Heures de consultation](https://uwaterloo.ca/french-studies/sites/ca.french-studies/files/uploads/files/fr400-w18.brouillon.pdf);
> [consultations](https://carleton.ca/french/wp-content/uploads/201930-FREN3050A-Guillaume-Gentil.pdf).
>  Heures de bureau ; ... de bureau « en ligne »
> ; heures de bureau virtuelles (!!). ([1](https://politique.uqam.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/43/Guide-de-lauxiliaire-denseignement.pdf),[2](https://philo.uqam.ca/wp-content/uploads/sites/72/2018/01/phi4014-1.pdf),[3](https://www.sse.ulaval.ca/docs/rapport_annuel/Rapport_Annuel_2012-2013_BSP_VF.pdf),[4](https://www.mcgill.ca/litterature/files/litterature/fren_441_plan_provisoire_site_dltc_automne_2020.pdf))

Et des références évidemment aux *rencontres, consultations, rendez-vous, rétroactions* etc. Dans un plan de cours on pourrait choisir un seul mot.

Je trouve *heures de disponbilité* vraiment clair mais il sert aussi dans certains contextes à désigner une plage horaire où l'on est disponible pour effectuer un quart de travail. La *consultation* rappelle le cabinet du médecin et un rapport différent. *Être au bureau* rappelle un lieu traditionnellement distinct du lieu de résidence en contexte de télétravail (« en ligne »), par exemple, et les *heures de bureau* est aussi employé pour un lieu de travail de professionnels ou plus généralement pour l'*ouverture*. Quant aux *heures au bureau*, elles ne sont pas toutes consacrées nécessairement aux rencontres et finalement je peux être ailleurs qu'*à mon bureau* pour rencontrer quelqu'un.

Comment: "Heures de consultation" me fait immédiatement penser à un médecin...

Answer (score 2):

Je parlerais d'**heures de permanence**. C'est un mot d'usage plus général que le contexte universitaire (d'ailleurs je n'en ai jamais entendu parler à ce sujet), par exemple dans le milieu politique, en particulier pour rencontrer les élus territoriaux.